# Accessing same singleton instance and destroying it when it is not required

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, mvvm, singleton

## (WPF MVVM)

I have a requirement where I need to access the same instance (following Singleton pattern) and also I want to create/access refreshed instance of above instance.

So what I did is, use singleton pattern(for both Model and ViewModel) at the required time and then destroy it (by setting the instance to value .i.e., giving Singleton.Instance = null) when I need new/refreshed version above Instance as the old object has been already stored in my ObservableCollection.

```
public sealed class SingletonViewModel
{
   private static SingletonViewModel instance=null;

   private SingletonViewModel ()
   {
   }

   public static SingletonViewModel Instance
   {
     get
     {
        if (instance==null)
        {
            instance = new SingletonViewModel ();
        }
        return instance;
      }
      set
      {
        instance = value;
      }
 }
 //I have an ObservableCollection of the SingletonViewModel class in other class. 
 //I am destroying the above instance by setting the Instance value to null.
  public void Destroy{
   SingletonModel.Instance = null;
   SingletonViewModel .Instance = null;
  }
 
  public String Header{
    get return SingletonModel.Instance.Header;
    set { SingletonModel.Instance.Header = value}
  }
```

**Though I destroy and try to access the above instance after calling function Destroy, my ObservableCollection is getting updated with the recent value of the above Instance.**

Comment: That's because you are using a static variable to hold the internal "instance" member, so all your copies in the observable collection will point to the same instance (static members are at class level not object level. If you are creating new instances then do you really need singleton?

Comment: Thanks for the response Piyush. The problem is, in backend I am serialising the Observable collections. So I need to access same instance in different classes.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, can you explain what you are trying to get to?
the reason might be because your observable collection has a reference to this static object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To put it in simple words. I want to use same instance of a class throughout my project and also I will be needing new instances of the same class. Is there any other design patterns that would help me to achieve this?